# jquery .one() fire query for one time but how can i able to fire query once if something is going wrong inside .one()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a login page and i want to submit the credencial once even the user click it multiple times thats why i want to use `.one()` but .one() have one problem that suppose user have some credencial proble then next time he fix it and try to send once again then .one() will not work. then you have to do some step . how to fix this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").one("click", function() {
    data = some data
    if data !==""{
        $.ajax({
            url: '/my url/',
            type: 'POST',                   
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data :data,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data){
                alert("done")   
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert("Some Error")      
                //here i want to do something so that if user click the submit button it will fire once                       
            }
        })
    }
    else
        //data is not there
        //here i want to do something so that if user click the submit button it will fire once 

    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You could bind the handler again:

```
$("#submit").one("click", function handler() { // give the function a name
    // keep a reference to the clicked element so that you can access it
    // inside callbacks
    var self = this; 


    // ...

    // when something went wrong, bind the handler again
    $(self).one('click', handler);
});
```

Comment: I don't know if you can tell be this, but compared to my example, which would be best performance-wise. For instance, binding and unbinding the event over and over again (lets assume a 50 times example). What whould it do with memory or performance?

Comment: @Martijn: I don't know, but you could use the Chrome developer tools to profile the code. In this specific use case, I don't think it matters because the user cannot interact with the UI so quickly that it would have any impact.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `one()` for this, but plain ajax. Instead of the way you do it now, make a variable called something like 'allowAjaxCheckLogin` and set it to true. In your regular click handler you check if it is true, if so, set it to false and do the ajax part. When ajax is done and the user needs to be able to do it again, set it back to true

---

```
var allowAjaxCheckLogin = true; // set to true, normal/startsituation allows a click

$('#submit').on('click', function(){
    // User may trigger actions:
    if( allowAjaxCheckLogin === true){
        allowAjaxCheckLogin = false; // Instantly set to false, if the user clicks again, nothing will happen

        $.ajax({ /* ajax settings here */ })
        .complete(function(){
            // this always fires, here you can check if you need to refresh the page to anochter location

           allowAjaxCheckLogin = true; // set back so the user may trigger again
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `on()` and `off()` for this like so

```
var inProgress = false;
$("#submit").on("click", function() {
    data = some data
    if(data !== "" && !inProgress ){
        inProgress = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/my url/',
            type: 'POST',                   
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data :data,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data){
                $('#submit').off();  // If is correct remove all event listeners 
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                loginFailed();                  
            }
        })
    }
    });

var loginFailed = function(){
   inProgress = false;
   alert("Some Error");
   // Display any Errors 
};
```

**off: http://api.jquery.com/off**

**on: http://api.jquery.com/on**

> We create a variable to check if there is a login in progress, if there isn't then we can try and login again, if there is then nothing will happen when you click, if the login was successful the event listener will be removed.

Comment: If I click `#submit` 10 times really fast, the ajax will fire those 10 times, not at all what `.one` does :)